# ¿Cómo sabe Sqlite qué registro actualizar sin un Where?

Tags: android-sqlite, xamarin.android

Tengo ésta clase, que es la tabla de la bd:

```
public class Clasificacion
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int IdClasificacion { get; set; }
        [NotNull]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        [NotNull]
        public bool Borrado { get; set; }
    }
```

Y aquí en controlador donde hago el Update

```
public void UpdateClasificacion(Clasificacion clasificacion)
            {
                string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "kobit.db3");
                var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
                db.Update(clasificacion);
            }
```

Cómo sabe sqlite que elemento actualizar de la tabla, si el parámetro que recibe es todo el objeto, y no recibe un campo como parámetro para actualizar, digamos el 'Where'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando marcas una propiedad con el atributo `PrimaryKey`, la libreria puede determinar fácilmente el filtro a utilizar. La busqueda de la propiedad con el atributo se hace utilizando reflection.

[Segun la documentacion](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/data/part_3_using_sqlite_orm/):

> Este atributo se puede aplicar a una propiedad entera para forzarla a
>   ser la clave principal de la tabla subyacente

Por lo que solo le bastaría buscar la propiedad que tiene el atributo `PrimaryKey`, obtener el nombre de la propiedad y su valor y construir el sql.

Ahora bien, si quieres saber como obtiene la informacion de cual campo es primary key en codigo, *problablemente* sea de la siguiente manera:

```
public PropertyInfo ObtenerPropiedadPrimaryKey(object objeto)
{
    Type = objeto.GetType();

    // buscamos todas las propiedades del objeto
    foreac(PropertyInfo property in type.GetProperties())
    {
        // obtenemos los atributos de la propiedad
        object[] attrs = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PrimaryKeyAttribute), false);

        // preguntamos si existe un attributo el tipo PrimaryKeyAttribute
        bool esPrimaryKey = attrs.Any(attr => attr is PrimaryKeyAttribute);


        if(esPrimaryKey)
        {
            return property;
        }

    }

    return null;
}
```

Uso:

```
Clasificacion objeto = new Clasificacion();
var propertInfo = ObtenerPropiedadPrimaryKey(objeto);
Console.WriteLine(propertyInfo.Name);// IdClasificacion
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta @Einer, no entendía cómo es que funcionaba el Update, muchas gracias, por tu excelente respuesta ;)